# Was this spontaneous BIOS update a sign of malware?

Tags: windows, powershell, bios

I disabled PowerShell 2.0 in Windows, which led the computer to prompt me to restart the device to put this change into effect. After shutdown, a BIOS update and windows update was performed. “HP BIOS update, visit hp.com/techcenter/startup for more information” etc etc.

I know a spontaneous BIOS update is a sign of malware and I’m now fairly worried - a few defender settings were turned off such as local authority protection. Firewall was fine, virus and threat protection said no action needed. Currently performing an offline scan.

Question: Is this expected behaviour? Is it possible that disabling PowerShell 2.0 leads to an automatic BIOS update?

Comment: BIOS updates can also be supplied via Windows Update. Check your update history: https://pureinfotech.com/check-update-history-windows-10/

Comment: [HP Systems BIOS Updates Will Use Windows Updates - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/177432-hp-systems-bios-updates-will-use-windows-updates.html)

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai, HP firmware update installed today, so that’ll be it. All good!

Comment: _"I know a spontaneous BIOS update is a sign of malware"_ - it's not

Answer (score 2):

Disabling PowerShell or any other like Windows App will not kick off a BIOS Update, and is not necessarily a sign of malware.

Did you have the HP Update App open?  That could prompt for a BIOS update.

Surface Machines run BIOS updates via Windows but I do not think many HP machines update via Windows updates

My Lenovo machines start in Windows but then restart to do the update. This is also not Windows Updates.

If nothing was open, do run a complete Anti Virus scan (Windows Defender both Online and then Offline) just to check.

**Take care with BIOS Updates:**

If you actually kick off a BIOS update, you need to have all apps closed, all files saved, and a secure source of power.  Certainly not a normal Windows every day update and something that must be taken very seriously to ensure BIOS update success.

Comment: [HP Systems BIOS Updates Will Use Windows Updates - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/177432-hp-systems-bios-updates-will-use-windows-updates.html)

Comment: Dell also definitely can and do supply BIOS updates via Windows Update, though mine is currently "optional".

Comment: Have done both scans and I cannot find the scan report in protection history - it says lasts can was a quick scan three days ago. I don’t remember this being different in the past. I always assumed if nothing was flagged then all is good. 

Task manager looks fine too, no new admin accounts.. I guess I have to assume all is well? Any other advice appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill ! Noted and appreciated

Comment: @user3709  - I have updated my answer and since all is good, the rest of my answer is how BIOS updates might look if they actually ran.